# Configure ldap client without yast

Tags: command-line, authentication, ldap, suse

I'm configuring an LDAP client in a large number of Suse servers. The only way that I know to do this is using Yast, and this way is slow. I can't find another way.

Anyone know another way to do this?

**Environment:**
SLES 11 SP3

Comment: [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/). Write your config once and then have Puppet push it to all of your clients.

Comment: This is the problem, I'm trying to map files modified by yast. Now, I'm versioning all files in the /etc/ directory using git, to track modifications. I know what files I need to modify on others Linux, like Debian, Centos, Fedora, but the Suse is a black hole to me.

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with SLES 11, I do know that older versions of OpenSuSE used /etc/ldap.conf and now uses sssd. I hope that might help....if you can give some more details I might be able to help you better.